# Abrir un formulario (hijo) en dos formularios (padre)

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario llamado `SearchCustomer` y dos formularios padres `(SharePoints and ViewCustomer)`, a la hora de abrir el formulario `SearchCustomer` en `ViewCustomer` si lo levanta y muestra datos, pero, a la hora de abrirlo en `SharePoints` ya no funciona, ya que crea un formulario "en blanco", ¿Alguna solución? , adjunto mi código:

**Formulario SearchCustomer:**

```
frmViewCustomer frmp;
        frmPuntoDeVenta frmPuntoDeVenta;
        public object frmglobal;
        public frmViewCustomer frmViewCustomer;

        public frmSearchCustomer(frmViewCustomer frmglobal)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frmp = frmglobal;
            
        }

        public frmSearchCustomer(frmPuntoDeVenta frmPuntoDeVenta)
        {
            this.frmPuntoDeVenta = frmPuntoDeVenta;
        }

        public frmSearchCustomer(object frmglobal, frmViewCustomer frmViewCustomer)
        {
            this.frmglobal = frmglobal;
            this.frmViewCustomer = frmViewCustomer;
        }
```

**Formulario ViewCustomer:**

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                frmSearchCustomer frmd = new frmSearchCustomer(this);
                frmd.Show();
            }
```

**Formulario SharePoints:**

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                frmSearchCustomer frmd = new frmSearchCustomer(this);
                frmd.Show();
            }
```

Pero no devuelve el formulario en `SharePoints`, sólo en `ViewCustomer`

Answer (score 0):

Investigando y debuggeando el código, logré encontrar el error, el error fue que no se estaba enviando correctamente el objeto global llamado `frmglobal` del formulario `SearchCustomer` a los formularios padres `(SharePoints y ViewCustomer)`

**Variables y funciones correctas en `SearchCustomer`**

```
frmViewCustomer frmp;
        frmPuntoDeVenta frmPuntoDeVenta;
        public object frmglobal;
        public frmViewCustomer frmViewCustomer;

        public frmSearchCustomer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        public frmSearchCustomer(object frmglobal, frmPuntoDeVenta frmPuntoDeVenta)
        {
            this.frmglobal = frmglobal;
            this.frmPuntoDeVenta = frmPuntoDeVenta;
        }

        public frmSearchCustomer(object frmglobal, frmViewCustomer frmViewCustomer)
        {
            this.frmglobal = frmglobal;
            this.frmViewCustomer = frmViewCustomer;
        }
```

**Código de apertura de formulario en los padres:**

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                frmSearchCustomer frmd = new frmSearchCustomer();
                frmd.Show();
            }
```